# Open Source Node.js (and Express) projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, open-source, coffeescript, express

What Open Source Node.js (and Express) projects are there? If CoffeeScript is used, that would be a huge plus too.

I need some inspiration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a list of projects, applications and sites using node.js. Some of them are probably open source and some use CofeeScript.

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node