# Starting up a node.js project

Tags: html, templates, node.js, mongodb

I'm about to start a project that's going to be a web site for storing photos. The method for uploading shall be drag and drop (from the desktop, same as Imgur), and it shall be possible to rate the photos as well commenting them.

For the project I'm going to use Node.js as well as HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery. The thing is that I'm a total newbie on Node.js and really could use some help regarding getting started. For the project I will of course need a database, and I have understood that MongoDB is a good choice. Is there any templates for this combination, so that I don't need to start from scratch?

I have installed Node.js and followed some tutorials but I really feel that I want to a template if there is one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by template... Do you want someone to write the whole application for you or are you asking for a similar application that's open source and that you can take inspiration from?

Comment: I guess something like HMTL5 Boilerplate or as you say a similar open source application to take inspiration from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said you are a beginner you can take the best independent modules for your project and start using. Instead of having a pre-defined package of necessary components as a single module. Problem is you may end up not understanding the whole pack and become more biased.

So,
I would suggest to use Expressjs (Best Choice) for url routing as mentioned above.

And,

File upload management:

[formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) - a high performance file upload server with file parts reading and progress notifiers etc.

Template Engine (Markup libs for your custom htmls):

[Jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade)

[coffeekup](https://github.com/mauricemach/coffeekup)

And consider [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) as well for prebuilt templates if in case you need it.

Mongo - Good choice.

[Mongo Modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-nosql-mongo)

These libs should help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) + [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

As a basic starting point, this is a popular framework:

http://expressjs.com/

Here you will find some links to example applications:

[Node.js Web Application examples/tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823403/node-js-web-application-examples-tutorials)

https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-nodejs

[Open Source Node.js (and Express) projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114176/open-source-node-js-and-express-projects)

Answer (score 0):

Express JS is good but I would recommend you have a look at [Railway JS](http://railwayjs.com/) as well. 
It is based on Express with support for numerous template engines and database adapters (including MongoDB). It is a lot more modular so you should not have much trouble working with it (in my opinion).
Check out: [Uploading images using Node.js, Express, and Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149545/uploading-images-using-nodejs-express-and-mongo) too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of resources that I have compiled using themeefy to start a node.js project http://www.themeefy.com/AvinashEga2/nodejs

Answer (score -1):

I think [Tower.js](http://towerjs.org/) is something like what you're after.